# Google Sheets : Show Browser msgBox when cell content changes to 'Yes'

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a very simple function that needs to display a message when the content of a cell changes from "No" to "Yes". The code I have written works well except that the message shows regardless of data entered. The message should show only if the cell content is "Yes"

Here is my code:

```
function onEdit(e){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var mftCell = sheet.getRange("E25:E26");
  if (mftCell="Yes");
  Browser.msgBox('Enter the % in the next cell!');
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems here.

1. The way your code is written now, the Browser.msgBox call is not dependent on the if statement. In other words, your code checks whether the value equals yes, then goes on to the next line regardless. You should try  `if (mftCell == "Yes") { Browser.msgBox(whatever); }`
2. The getRange() method returns a range, not the values in the range. You should add a call to .getValues() after your call to get the range. See this: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()
3. Remember that getValues returns a 2-dimensional array, even if there is only one cell, so you'll need to access the value by something like `myValues[0][0]` in order to see the value of a particular cell.
4. You want to call .toLowerCase() in a comparison where a user enters text in a field. "yes" == "Yes" evaluates to false, so you should have something like `if (values[0][0].toLowerCase( == "yes"`  or users who enter "YEs" or "yes" or whatever won't trigger your message.

Also, you need '==' not '=' in an if statement.

Comment: Thanks. Working well.